# Adding noise to OFDMA system in Matlab

Tags: matlab, noise, telecommunication

I am building an OFDMA system to calculat BER and I am having trouble introducing noise accurately into the system that takes into account multiple users.

I modelling the noise as AWGN. I have vector (y) with complex time domain signal that I want to add noise to.

Can upload the full code if needed. But below is where I am at currently which is not right.

```
%% Channel %%

%add noise to this

%EsNo = EbNo + 10*log10(bitsPerSubcarrier)+10*log10(users); %this is for SCFDMA

noise = y + (1/sqrt(2))*(randn + randn*i); %???

EsNo = (randn + randn*i) + EbNo;

% xmnoise = awgn(y, EsNo, 'measured');

xmnoise = awgn(y, EbNo, 'measured');
```